# find_elements not selecting all the elements (python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get all the elements with bg-primary class and save their href (hyperlink) value in a variable.
Here is my code:

```
elems = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME , "bg-primary")
    
    for elem in elems:
        if (elem.get_attribute("href")):
            print(elem.get_attribute("href"))
```

[And this is the website's code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7AFL.png) which has class: `"bg-primary"` I'm trying to search for it yet I'm not getting any results.

That's what I tried. This code block is dynamically activated on the site and I have WebDriverWait elements for waiting on the element to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Given the HTML:

[image: html]

you have to make a few adjustments as follows:

- The class attribute of the `<a>` element contains multiple values and *`bg-primary`* is one of them.
- Additionally the elements looks to be dynamic element.

---

### Solution

To extract all the elements with *`bg-primary`* class and save their *`href`* value you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.bg-primary")))])
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@class, 'bg-primary')]")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.bg-primary")))])
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 95, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: (no message)
Error says timeout so it didn't find it at all

Comment: I feel like there is a chance for a whole driver to change when I load the element. Could that be an issue even when I'm not leaving the website?